# Cumulative sum with max date group by month year and id

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Now i need to make similar query but need to several criteria
Here is my table

```
`transaksi` (`transid`, `idpinj`, `tanggal`,`sisapokok`, `sisajasa`
(1, 1, '2018-01-01', 1000, 100, 1),
(2, 1, '2018-01-05', 1000, 100, 3),
(3, 2, '2018-02-04', 1000, 100, 4),
(4, 2, '2018-02-08', 1000, 100, 5),
(5, 1, '2018-02-19', 1000, 100, 3),
(6, 3, '2018-02-22', 1000, 100, 2),
(7, 2, '2018-03-09', 1000, 100, 3),
(8, 3, '2018-03-10', 1000, 100, 3)
(9, 3, '2018-03-12', 1000, 100, 4)
(10, 1, '2018-03-17', 1000, 100, 4)
(11, 4, '2018-03-19', 1000, 100, 3)
(12, 2, '2018-03-20', 1000, 100, 4)
```

[DB Fiddle table](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7XRrJFpRb1Xzss1G1Up3nX/10)

From the table above i need to get output as follow

```
Month         sisapokok    sisajasa
Jan-2018      1000         100       ->row2
Feb-2018      4000         400       ->+ row3+5
Mar-2018      12000        1200      ->+ row9+10+11+12
```

- First I need to get sum(sisapokok) and sum(sisajasa) for each idpinj where date is max(tanggal), status between 3 and 4. This value then sum as total per month
- Make cumulative sum each month for the last 12 month

I try this query but it get the max(date) from all records not max(date) by month and each idpinj.

```
SELECT  a.idpinj,a.sisapokok
FROM    transaksi a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  idpinj, MAX(tanggal) tgl
            FROM    transaksi
            GROUP BY idpinj
        ) b ON a.idpinj = b.idpinj
                AND a.tanggal = b.tgl  
ORDER BY `a`.`idpinj` ASC
```

Comment: It's a pity the dbfiddle data does not match the question data or the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking for but see if this helps:

```
select monthyear, sum(sisapokok)sisapokok, sum(sisajasa)sisajasa from (
select   cast(month(tanggal) as varchar)+'-'+cast(year(tanggal) as varchar) monthyear, sum(sisapokok)sisapokok, sum(sisajasa)sisajasa
from #transaksi
 group by  cast(month(idpinj) as varchar)+'-'+cast(year(tanggal) as varchar) , tanggal) a
 group by monthyear
```

Comment: try your query and replace varchar to char but still got error "near group by cast....

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: No, i'm using MySQL

Comment: OK try using 'extract' instead of month() and year()

Comment: + is a sql server concat function just use concat

Comment: same error, still can't make it works... select monthyear, sum(sisapokok)sisapokok, sum(sisajasa)sisajasa from (
select   cast(extract(month from tanggal) as char)+'-'+cast(extract(year from tanggal) as char) monthyear, sum(sisapokok)sisapokok, sum(sisajasa)sisajasa
from #transaksi
 group by  cast(extract(month from tanggal) as char)+'-'+cast(extract(year from tanggal) as char) , tanggal) a
 group by monthyear

Comment: error gone by removing hashtag # but the query result is wrong. monthyear return 2019,2020,2021 see here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7XRrJFpRb1Xzss1G1Up3nX/11

Comment: Give unexpected result. My expected results is as per my 1st post. Get sum(sisapokok) for each idpinj which has max(tanggal) and then cumulative sum per month. select monthyear, sum(sisapokok)sisapokok, sum(sisajasa)sisajasa from (
select  CONCAT(LEFT(monthname(tanggal),3),'-', year(tanggal)) monthyear, sum(sisapokok)sisapokok, sum(sisajasa)sisajasa
from transaksi
 group by  CONCAT(LEFT(monthname(tanggal),3),'-', year(tanggal)), tanggal) a
 group by monthyear

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fiddle data

```
select yyyy,mm,
        @s:=@s+sisapokok sisapokok,
        @t:=@t+sisajasa sisajasa
from
(
select yyyy,mm,sum(sisapokok) sisapokok,sum(sisajasa) sisajasa
from
(
select year(tanggal) yyyy,month(tanggal) mm, sisapokok,sisajasa
from transaksi t
join
(
select year(tanggal) yyyy,month(tanggal) mm,idpinj,max(transid) maxid
from `transaksi`
where status in(3,4)
group by year(tanggal),month(tanggal),idpinj
) s on s.maxid = transid
) t
group by yyyy,mm
) u
,(select @s:=0,@t:=0) r
order by yyyy,mm

+------+------+-----------+----------+
| yyyy | mm   | sisapokok | sisajasa |
+------+------+-----------+----------+
| 2018 |    1 |      2000 |     2003 |
| 2018 |    2 |      5000 |     2303 |
| 2018 |    3 |     13000 |     3103 |
+------+------+-----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the inner query finds the last relevant id and the code progresses outward to use variables to calculate running totals.